# proper set up of parsing custom logs with logstash to kibana, i see no errors and no data

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I'm playing a bit with kibana to see how it works.

i was able to add nginx log data directly from the same server without logstash and it works properly. but using logstash to read log files from a different server doesn't show data. no error.. but no data.

I have custom logs from [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) that runs some PHP script for me and the format of the messages are:

`Timestamp [LogLevel]: msg`

example:

```
2021-02-21 21:34:17 [DEBUG]: file size matches written file size 1194179
```

so my gork filter is:

```
"%{DATESTAMP:timestamp} \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\]: %{GREEDYDATA:msg}"
```

I checked with [Gork Validator](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) and the syntax matches the file format.

i've got files that contain the suffix `out` that are debug level, and files with suffix `error` for error level.

so to configure logstash on the kibana server, i added the file `/etc/logstash/conf.d/pipeline.conf` with the following:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => 5544
    }
}
filter {
 grok {
   match => {"message"=>"%{DATESTAMP:timestamp} \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\]: %{GREEDYDATA:msg}"} 
 }
mutate {
    rename => ["host", "server"]
    convert => {"server" => "string"}
}
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
        user => "<USER>"
        password => "<PASSWORD>"
    }
}
```

I needed to rename the `host` variable to `server` or I would get errors like `Can't get text on a START_OBJECT` and `failed to parse field [host] of type [text]`

on the 2nd server where the pm2 logs reside I configure filebeat with the following:

```
- type: filestream
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /home/ubuntu/.pm2/*-error-*log
  fields:
   level: error
- type: filestream
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs/*-out-*log
  fields:
   level: debug
```

I tried to use `log` and not `filestream` the results are the same.
but it makes sense to use `filestream` since the logs are updated constantly on ?

so i have `logstash` running on one server and `filebeat` on the other, opened firewall ports, i can see they're connecting but i don't see any new data in the Kibana logs dashboard relevant to the files i fetch with logstash.

filebeat log always shows this line `Feb 24 04:41:56 vcx-prod-backup-01 filebeat[3797286]: 2021-02-24T04:41:56.991Z        INFO        [file_watcher]        filestream/fswatch.go:131        Start next scan` and something about analytics metrics so it looks fine, and still no data.

I tried to provide here as much information as I can, i'm new to kibana, i have no idea why data is not shown in kibana if there are no errors.

I thought maybe i didn't escaped the square brackets properly in gork filter so I tried using `"%{DATESTAMP:timestamp} \\[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\\]: %{GREEDYDATA:msg}"` which replaces `\[` with `\\[` but the results are the same.

any information regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated.

#update
ֿ
using stack version 7.11.1

I changed back to `log` instead of `filestream` based on @leandrojmp recommendations.

I checked for `harverser.go` related lines i filebeat and I found these:

```
Feb 24 14:16:36 SERVER filebeat[4128025]: 2021-02-24T14:16:36.566Z        INFO        log/harvester.go:302        Harvester started for file: /home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs/cdr-ssh-out-1.log
Feb 24 14:16:36 SERVER filebeat[4128025]: 2021-02-24T14:16:36.567Z        INFO        log/harvester.go:302        Harvester started for file: /home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs/cdr-ftp-out-0.log
```

and I also noticed that when i configured the output to stdout, i do see the events that are coming from the other server. so logstash do receive them properly but for some reason i don't see them in kiban.

Comment: Which version of the stack are you using? The `filestream` is still experimental, I would suggest that you change it back to `log` until you find out what is not working. Change it for `log`, restart filebeat and look for the lines with `harvester.go` in your filebeat log.

Comment: If using `stdout` you see the events then the problem could be in the communication between logstash and elasticsearch or in elasticsearch when trying to ingest the documents. You should look both logs, the logstash log and elasticsearch log to see if there is any relevant information, any error or warning.

Comment: @leandrojmp - for some reason didn't think about checking the elasticsearch log, i see authentication errors that don't come from logstash. now that i know more i'm purging the cluster, re-configuring and lets see how it goes :)

Comment: @leandrojmp - i tried creating a secured user last time, now i left the configuration as it. no errors in any logs, and still no data in kibana. curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/logstash-2021.02.24-000001/_search shows data from the logs. why don't i see them in kibana web interface under logs ?

Comment: You can check the indices in elasticsearch using the [cat indices API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html), for example, using `curl http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices` will show you all your index.

Comment: @leandrojmp - found a solution! thank you so much!

Comment: Did you create an index pattern? I do not use the logs interface in Kibana, but if I'm not wrong you need to create an index pattern and configure the Logs to use your index pattern, per default it will look for `filebeat-*` index only.

Comment: @leandrojmp - that's exactly it. writing an answer as we speak. can you post this solution so i'll mark your response as correct ? i want to write a log answer just for other people to understand what was going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have output using both `stdout` and `elasticsearch` outputs but you do not see the logs in Kibana, you will need to create an `index pattern` in Kibana so it can show your data.

After creating an `index pattern` for your data, in your case the `index pattern` could be something like `logstash-*` you will need to configure the Logs app inside Kibana to look for this index, per default the Logs app looks for `filebeat-*` index.

Answer (score 0):

ok... so @leandrojmp helped me a lot in understanding what's going on with kibana. thank you! all the credit goes to you! just wanted to write a log answer that may help other people overcome the initial setup.

lets start fresh

I wanted one kibana node that monitors custom logs on a different server.
I have ubuntu latest LTS installed on both, added the deb repositories, installed kibana, elsaticsearch and logstash on the first, and filebeat on the 2nd.

basic setup is without much security and SSL which is not what i'm looking for here since i'm new to this topic, everything is mostly set up.

in `kibana.yml` i changed the host to `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost` so i can connect from outside, and in logstash i added the following conf file:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => 5544
    }
}
filter {
 grok {
   match => {"message"=>"%{DATESTAMP:timestamp} \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\]: %{GREEDYDATA:msg}"} 
 }
mutate {
    rename => ["host", "server"]
    convert => {"server" => "string"}
}
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    }
}
```

i didn't complicate things and didn't need to set up additional authentication.

my filebeat.yml configuration:

```
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /home/ubuntu/.pm2/*-error-*log
  fields:
   level: error
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs/*-out-*log
   level: debug
```

i started everything, no errors in any logs  but still no data in kibana, since i had no clue how elasticsearch stored it's data, i needed to find out how can i connect to elasticsearch and see if the data is there, so i executed `curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v`  and noticed a logstash index, so i executed `curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/logstash-2021.02.24-000001/_search` and i noticed that the log data is presented in the database.

so it must means that it's something with kibana. so using the web interface of kibana under settings I noticed a configuration called `Index pattern for matching indices that contain log data` and the input there did not match the logstash index name, so i appended `,logstash*` to it and voila! it works :)

thanks